# android service questions

Tags: android, service, alarmmanager

I read this http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/services.html and there it say the lifecylce of the service depends on how I started it either via onStartCommand() and the service runs (almost) for ever or via onBind() and the service only runs as long as my application does.

Now I read http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/AlarmService.html there the service is started via the AlarmManager. Neither the onBind() nor the onStartCommand() methods are used. How is the lifecylce of this service now?

Second question, is somehow (how?) ensured that if the application is started again and again that the service is only scheduled once?

Thanks, A.

Answer (score 0):

> or via onBind() and the service only runs as long as my application does.

More accurately, it runs until all `bindService()` calls have matching `unbindService()` calls.

> Neither the onBind() nor the onStartCommand() methods are used

That is not a `Service`, despite the name. It is an `Activity`.

> Second question, is somehow (how?) ensured that if the application is started again and again that the service is only scheduled once?

The `PendingIntent` will be equivalent for the two `setRepeating()` calls, so the second `setRepeating()` should overwrite the first. That being said, this is a sloppy example.

Comment: but the activity calls a service, this one http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/AlarmService_Service.html